# Pandas: change values in selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following source dataframe

[image]

and would like to change values in selected columns to reciprocal. When I try to run the following script

```
df_bets.loc[:,'B365H':] = 1/df_bets.loc[:,'B365H':]
```

I get the warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Is there a better way how to do it?

Comment: Problem is in code before `df_bets.loc[:,'B365H':] = 1/df_bets.loc[:,'B365H':]`, how is created `df_bets` ?

Comment: Like this:  `df_bets = df[cols_bets]` where `df` is a source dataframe and `cols_bets` is list of columns.

Comment: yop, use `df_bets = df[cols_bets].copy()`